# Problems using firebase java admin sdk with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Is anyone successfully using the java firebase admin sdk with apache tomcat?
I'm experiencing big problems, probably related to the internal messaging system (io.netty) used by the firebase sdk: after initializing Firebase (FirebaseApp.initializeApp() which "apparently" ends correctly), every firebase API call gets stuck.
If I start a console application with the same Java version on the same server with the same service_account_file, all works fine, therefore we can exclude authentication (or network) problems.

I'm using Java 11 (OpenJDK), Tomcat 9.0.80 and firebase-admin 9.2.0 on a linux server.
I put the initialization code for firebase in my ServletContextListener.contextInitialized():

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(CaasaAdminServletListener.class).info("[init]");
String serviceAccountKey = sce.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/firebase.json");
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(CaasaAdminServletListener.class).info("[init] serviceAccountKey= "+serviceAccountKey);
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(serviceAccountKey);            
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
              .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
              .setDatabaseUrl("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/")
              .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(CaasaAdminServletListener.class).info("[init] FirebaseApp.initializeApp OK");
```

After initialization (called once when my webapp gets deployed), when I try to use whatever firebase API in my servlet (synchronous or asynchronous) it gets stuck (or timeout).
Here an example of my code in a simple servlet ( in the processRequest method ):

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
database.getReference().child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in initializing the library within the webapp lifecycle based on how Tomcat manages the loading of libraries (and static objects in particular) and sharing between different contexts.

Please note that:

*) I also tested my code on a console application on the same server and it works fine: I'm able to access my database and to read or set values, using both synchronous and asynchronous API
*) I've tried initializing firebase in a static block, in the servlet.init method or simply just before using the API (processRequest), but nothing changes.
*) Comparing debug logs from firebase lib between the console app (working) and the tomcat webapp (not working) I noticed the messages relating to the initialization of the internal messaging system of the io.netty lib are completely missing. Here is the common (initial) part of the debug log I obtain in both cases:

```
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using Log4J as the default logging framework
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 11
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) di
sabled
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @6c382782
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, {int,long}): unavailable
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 7677673472 bytes (maybe)
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /tmp (java.io.tmpdir)
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
```

while I can read the following log only in the working case (console app):

```
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor - -Dio.netty.globalEventExecutor.quietPeriodSeconds: 1
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl - netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext - Default protocols (JDK): [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext - Default cipher suites (JDK): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 17423 (auto-detected)
12 10 2023 10:27:41 DEBUG firebase-database-worker io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
....
```